# Run a single class file in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I created new Objective-C class and I am trying to use `NSLog` to test outputs from the class before calling the class methods in my iPhone app's main view.

In Netbeans, doing Java Projects, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> used to work to run the single class file. I could not find that functionality in Xcode 4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Good Lord - the guy asks a valid question (seeing how it pertains to another programming language) and he gets down voted?

Comment: Classes in C and C-like languages aren't as self-contained as in Java.  For instance, main() should only be defined once, and is not entered in every class it's defined in (in fact, it's a linker error if main() is defined more than once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't do this, you run your entire application. If you want to test a class you should look into writing unit tests. http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide

Comment: Which is to say you write a program that uses the class. But with the formal concept of validating it does things the way your test expects. Which doesn't tell you everything. Classes and objects don't live in their own world very often.